# Selenium - как получить html код страницы для работы с BeutifulSoup4?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

У меня нет проблем с подключением к сайту, все открываеться но я получаю не то что мне нужно вот код с помощью которого пытаюсь получить html страницу ютуба:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/AXSTHXTIC666/videos')
main_page = driver.find_element("html")

print(main_page)
```

Что я получаю:

[image: Вторая часть ошибки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Особо нет смысла использовать для этого слениум. Скорее всего у YouTube есть API. Так же спарсить что то с ютуба можно просто через requests + bs4 скорее всего. Это точно будет быстрее чем селениум.

Если очень хочется использовать селениум, код ниже должен работать.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/AXSTHXTIC666/videos')
main_page = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')


print(main_page.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```